# Bivariate Normal Distribution

Tags: probability

Suppose $f(x,y)$ is bivariate normal. You are given $E(X)$, $E(Y)$, $\text{Var}(X)$ and $\text{Var}(Y)$. You are also given $\rho$ the correlation coefficient. How would one find $\text{Var}(Y|X=k)$? Would you use [the total law of variance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7040/conditional-and-total-variance)? We know that $\rho = \frac{\text{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sigma_x \sigma_y}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions).